# Conjugations of ゆく vs. いく

Tags: conjugations

What are the conjugations for [行く]{ゆく}? Are they the same as [行く]{いく} except for the plain form? I tried to google around for a conjugation table, but I can't find any.

The closest that I found is this:

https://www.tanoshiijapanese.com/dictionary/conjugation_details.cfm?entry_id=114066&element_id=5224

But I'm not sure if they're just autogenerated or how accurate it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modern Japanese, ゆく is not used in the -te, -ta, -tari, -tara(ba), -tarō, or -tatte forms, i.e. the forms that undergo 音便. If you need to use these forms, you would use those of いく instead. So things like 出てゆいて on the page you linked are incorrect. Otherwise, ゆく conjugates like a regular consonant-stem verb. Here are the main forms:

辞書形　ゆく
連用形　ゆき
マス形　ゆきます
否定形　ゆかない
　バ形　ゆけば
命令形　ゆけ
意向形　ゆこう
受身形　ゆかれる
使役形　ゆかせる
可能形　ゆける

Comment: I was under the impression that ゆいて・ゆいた・等 are the regular forms for ゆく, evincing the same き→い kind of 音便 that we see with verbs like 書く or 向く.  Is this restricted to certain dialects?

Comment: @Eiríkr Sorry, I don't know much about dialects. I'm only familiar with Tokyo Japanese, and I've never seen or heard ゆいて and such. I checked スーパー大辞林, and it says, "連用形の音便形は，現代語では「いく」の「いっ（て）」「いっ（た）」の形しか用いられない。ただし古くは「ゆく」にも音便形として「ゆい（て）」があった", so it doesn't seem like they are standard.

Comment: I've noticed in other entries that monolingual JA dictionaries focus on 標準語【ひょうじゅんご】 or "standard Japanese" as taught in schools and used in news broadcasting.  I've learned over time that 「古くは」 and similar qualifying expressions used in dictionaries apply to 標準語, but not necessarily to other varieties of Japanese -- even varieties with large populations of speakers, like 関西弁【かんさいべん】.  Curious if you or anyone else hears more about these ゆいて・ゆいた forms.

Answer (score -2):

ゆく and いく are two of the readings for 行く. Note that, ゆく and いく are not two different verbs but two different readings for 行く.
When a verb conjugates the okurigana changes. So, the conjugation for 行く(not いく or ゆく) would be い/ゆ + the corresponding okurigana.Thus, the conjugation doesn't change for a different reading.
Note that the readings for the same word may not be interchangeable. Personally, I haven't seen the ゆく reading of 行く being used in polite form.

Comment: I have never heard anyone say ゆって or ゆった for 行って or 行った. Those are only for 言って and 言った.

Comment: The reading ゆく is sort of an archaic reading for the verb.  Though they are not used much, you can still see this reading used in songs and some forms of pop culture.

Comment: It was a popular reading pre-war though not used much nowadays.